# What does PrivateAssets='All' mean?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, fody-propertychanged

When I build my .NET Core (NETStandard v2.0) project I am getting the following warning:

> ViewModels: [FodyPackageReference] Fody: The package reference for PropertyChanged.Fody
> does not contain PrivateAssets='All'

The warning is in reference to the [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) NuGet package.

While the warning does not stop the build, I would like to resolve the warning. However, I don't understand what it is trying to communicate.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`PrivateAssets` is a metadata tag used to control dependency assets.

> You might be using a dependency purely as a development harness and might not want to expose that to projects that will consume your package. In this scenario, you can use the PrivateAssets metadata to control this behavior.
>
> [Package references (PackageReference) in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets)

In your case, unless you want to expose `PropertyChanged.Fody` to a consumer (i.e. you are releasing a library), setting `PrivateAssets` to `All` in your .csproj file will remove the warning.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody" Version="3.3.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great and helped. I discovered, that sometimes the notation in the .csproj is like: `<PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody">
      <Version>3.3.1</Version>       <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference> `

Comment: It was changed. Please, update the comment with: `<PackageReference Include="Costura.Fody" Version="5.3.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>`.

Comment: @rios0rios0 What has changed? Also, why does it matters what you put in the Include or Version attributes? This question and answer is about the PrivateAssets attribute, not about a specific dependency.

Comment: @RyanPayne please, try to do what you said in the new version of the packages. And you'll get an error. There's no property called "PropertyChanged.Fody". It doesn't exist anymore. The property "PrivateAssets" only works in the declaration of the package, as I said.

Comment: @rios0rios0 Costura.Fody is a completely separate package from PropertyChanged.Fody (see https://github.com/Fody/Costura). I just tried it out and the above code still works fine.

Comment: When I add this fix I have an exclamation mark in Dependencies->Packages->PropertyChanged.Fody

Comment: @raV720 I'm not sure what you mean. This isn't really a fix but an optional parameter. I can't really help you debug your issue without more information.

Comment: @RyanPayne Visual Studio 2022 v17.1.6 -> create new WPF project with .net 6.0 -> add PropertyChanged.Fody nuget -> the warning about PrivateAssets='All' appears -> set PrivateAssets='All' in project project file as described in your answer -> immediately exclamation mark in Dependencies appears

Comment: @raV720 interesting. If I were you, I'd post a new Stack Overflow question about the specific issue you're experiencing.